# Ruby CSV parsing Count Column Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have this CSV File:

```
col1,  col2,     col3,     col4, col5
name1, contact1, addr, ess1, zip1, comment1    <==
name2, contact2, address2, zip2, comment2
name3, contact3, address3, zip3, comment3
```

When I count the columns:

```
columns = CSV.read(file_path, headers: true).headers
```

when the second line (1st record/row) has more columns than the column headers count, this will return the larger number: `6`.

Printed headers: `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, nil`

I want to count the **CSV Column Headers** properly to compare it with the column count of each record/row.

```
columns = CSV.read(file_path, headers: true).headers
logger.info("COLUMN NAMES: #{columns.inspect}")
logger.info("COLUMN COUNT: #{columns.count}")

CSV.foreach(file_path, option) do |row|
  # Check if a row columns matches file column headers count
  if row.count != columns.count
    logger.info("Error: Row count not match.")
    File.delete(lock_file)
    exit
  end
end
```

I want to match the `COLUMN HEADERS COUNT` to `RECORD COLUMNS COUNT` before saving the record. In case the record has more columns than the header, there is a possible occurrence of a comma `,` somewhere in the record.

This might also mean the user has supplied invalid record data and and record columns will not match each field on the DB table.

Comment: Perhaps count how many `nil`'s are in the first row?

Comment: @c650 I bet there are no `nil`'s in the first row as it exceeds the number of column headers.. headers: `5` | row columns: `6`

Comment: It might help us answer you if you explain why you want to do that. This sounds kind of like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)".

Comment: @theTinMan thank you for pointing that out. I updated the question and added the EDIT part why I need this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get `nil` in your headers as long you have extra columns in any other row, so, since you have 6 columns in the first row, you get:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, nil
```

One solution will be to delete any `nil` values found at the end of the `headers` array, something like this:

```
columns = CSV.read(file_path, headers: true).headers
columns.pop while columns.last.nil?

# ...
```

Now, in your example, you will get this headers:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

The count will be `5`, so your code should now work as expected.

Comment: This seems a pretty clean idea. Thank you for your help!